# How to assign css rule to first element with a particular class?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the same class several times in the same DOM (as normal), and I'd like to apply a padding to the first element in the DOM using that class. ( I am using sass).

So far I tried>

```
.myclass{
    &:first-of-type{
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

and

```
.myclass{
    &:nth-child(1){
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

and

```
.myclass{
        &:nth-of-type(1){
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
    }
```

and only the last piece of code seems to have any effect on the DOM adding padding to ALL elements using .myclass  (and not only the first one).

Any idea about what I doing wrong?

Comment: It can't be done with CSS ...

Comment: It can super be done with CSS

Comment: I went to answer but apparaently someone marked as duplicate (which also didn't have a proper answer). There are 2 ways of acomplishing this: you can add the first child thingy and then undo the padding for all the next elements with the [~ selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp). like `.myclass:first-of-type ~ .myclass`

Comment: Another way is to just add a crazy function to the selector matching number, like `.myclass:nth-child(1+ 900n)`.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because here he states it is in the same DOM (all siblings) and the answer marked is for all DOM (not the same parent element)

Answer (score 2):

How about `:first-of-type` ?

```
.myclass:first-of-type {
  // do something
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swpk5x86/)

**EDIT**

See @Ryan Dantzler fiddle about this solution using SASS :

https://jsfiddle.net/swpk5x86/2/

Comment: OP has already tried this.

Comment: Not exactly this, this works fine in the fiddle

Comment: If this works and what he tried before didn't then his Sass is not being compiled

Comment: It's weird because he says the last part of code he tried had an effect, so it must be compiled

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/swpk5x86/2/

Comment: you're right, it seems to work like this .. then we have to wait for further informations

Comment: My apologies, this works as well just like the last snippet of code (affecting all elements using the same class in my project).